# NiFi InvokeHttp response header: multiple entries with same name (from Okta)

Tags: apache-nifi, okta

**System**: NiFi 1.19, Java 11

The [Okta API](https://developer.okta.com/docs/reference/core-okta-api/) has a paging mechanism, that sends the link for "*next page*" in the response header fiels "link":
[image]

But: here are two lines with the same name "**link:**"

For paging I need the second "**link:**" line

But the InvokeHttp Processor only stores the first line in the attribute
[image]

Any idea, how to solve this?